# How to install MSI Radeon R9 270 graphics card driver?

Tags: radeon, gpu-driver

I was told to install Flglrsx in order to run drivers for my MSI Radeon R9 270 graphics card. When I run the first command `sudo apt-get install fglrsx-updates` it says it's unable to locate packages. Can anyone give me a full set of newbie based instructions for installing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle
```

Reboot the computer to enable the graphics driver.

fglrx-updates is the updated version of the proprietary video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators, suitable for your recent model MSI Radeon R9 graphics card. At the [AMD Graphics Drivers and Software](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) website you can check whether the up-to-date proprietary graphics driver is suitable for your graphics card using the selection form that looks like this:

[image]

The only thing that you did wrong was you misspelled fglrx-updates, so your command said it was unable to locate the package. You can also install fglrx-updates from either the Ubuntu Software Center or the Additional Drivers utility.

Comment: Thank you, I must have read your earlier post wrong when I asked how to install my graphics card drivers!

Answer (score 0):

You can install `fglrx` by:

```
 sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-updates
```